# How to surround multiple lines individually with surround.vim

Tags: vim, plugins, emmet, surround

I have these three (or more) lines that I want to surround with li (or any other) tag :

Bananas
Citrus
Orange

I can do it this way: `qaysstli>jq` then `2@a`.

Is there a way to do this faster and without a macro ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Select visually all the lines with `<S-v>`
2. Type `:norm yss<li>` then `<CR>`

Result:

```
<li>Bananas</li>
<li>Citrus</li>
<li>Orange</li>
```

Ranges are good too: `:.,+2norm yss<li><CR>` does the same, as well as `:1,3norm yss<li><CR>`.

Answer (score 10):

Use Visual Block and then surround.

`<c-v>` to start visual block mode and then move to the last line of the text. Use `$` to select to the end of each line then `S<li>`

All together:

```
<c-v>2j$S<li>
```

Comment: I like this one better than mine.

Answer (score 5):

The faster way I can think about it using [zencoding-vim](https://github.com/mattn/zencoding-vim). With that plugin you can select visually the text, then you can type <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> and then type:

```
ul > li*
```

Adn you'll get the list. It looks like magic and it's very fast too.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I was pretty sure it was also possible with zencoding but didnt know how too. Thanks !

Comment: More than welcome. Please accept it if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: I accepted the other answer cause it's better related to the title of my question, but I'll probably use your answer more often when coding ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient way but found it helpful as a newbie, you can use Visual Block twice to add the tag at the beginning and at the end of the word.

1. `<c-v>` to start the visual block and then use `I` to insert the first `<li>`, end with `[esc]`.
2. `<c-v>` to start the visual block and then use `$` to select to the end of the block. Use `A` and then append `<li>`, end with `[esc]`.

All together: `<c-v>2jI<li>[esc]` and `<c-v>2j$A<li>[esc]`